# criar Linked no MySQL entre instâncias diferentes

Tags: mysql, linked-server

Olá,
Tenho a instância A (Local) e uma outra instância B, preciso fazer uma consulta onde tenho a tabela A (instância Local) relacionar com a tabela B da (instância B) é possível ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A engine MySQL [FEDERATED engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) até tem uma funcionalidade parecida com a Linked Server do SQL Server, dá uma olhada para ver se te ajuda.

Fora isso, nativamente o MySQL não tem esse tipo de funcionalidade.